# What is a sleep message in Colloquy?

Tags: macos, irc, colloquy

In Colloquy, there are options for a quit message and a sleep message.
I know what the quit message does. When you disconnect, this is the message sent, correct?

However, I have no idea what this sleep message is. It's not an a default reason for away, from what I've seen. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put your computer to sleep (standby), Colloquy disconnects all active connections.

The sleep message is used as quit message in this case.

[Source](http://source.colloquy.info/svn/trunk/Controllers/MVApplicationController.m): See `- (void) receiveSleepNotification:(NSNotification *)`